# The differences between ssh hostname and ssh[user@]hostname

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

When I issue `ssh -v hostname`, it tells me successful. But permission denied(publickey) when issuing `ssh -v user@hostname`. What's the differences between them? And I try to solve this problem by some ways, but weren't effective. Such as:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
Restorecon ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I guess the problem is about context, because after issuing `ssh -v hostname`, the debug information tells me unable to get valid context. And issuing ssh[user@]hostname it authorized id_rsa, id_ecdsa, and id_ed25519 and skiping id_dsa (probably the config setting).

Comment: It's possible you've elided too much information. Is the "user" that you're connecting as with user@hostname the same as your local username?

Comment: i connected the user's usename rather than local username

Answer (score 3):

`ssh hostname` uses the account name defined in the configuration (if available) or the local user name. `ssh username@hostname` uses `username`, obviously.

`ssh -v` (or `-vv`) should tell you at the beginning which account name is used.